# VBA - Copy Excel table to Word - Works on PC, Fails on Mac

Tags: macos, excel, vba, ms-word, copy

I have written some code VBA which copies data from Excel to Word when an Excel cell is clicked.  The process is as follows:

```
1. Opens an already created word document, duplicates the word document, and then closes the original document; leaving open the copy (duplicate) for further modification.

2. The code then finds and replaces some placeholder values within the word document with values from the Excel document.

3. The code then deletes 2 different tables (1 at a time), row by row, and replaces each table (1 at a time) with a table copied from Excel.

4. The code then displays a message to the user that all has been completed and exits.
```

All code works perfectly on my PC, but fails on a colleagues MAC, stating the "Error: 4605 - Command is not available" and failing on the `wrdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True` line of code.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Copy2Word()

    Dim wrdApp As Object
    Dim tempDoc As Word.Document
    Dim mrgDoc As Word.Document
    Dim NumPay As Integer
    Dim cll As Excel.Range

    'GET NUMBER OF PAYMENTS SELECTED FOR USE BELOW
    NumPay = Notated.Cells(Data.Range("DV2").Value, Data.Range("DV3").Value).Value

    'GET LOCATION OF WORD FILE FROM USER
    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FName = False Then
        usrErr = 1
        GoTo ErrHnd
    End If

    'RECORD THE WORD FILE LOCATION ON HIDDEN SHEET FOR USE BY OTHER MACROS
    MergeData.Range("B2").Value = FName

    'CREATE WORD OBJECT
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    'DISPLAY WORD APPLICATION
    On Error Resume Next
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    wrdApp.Activate
    On Error GoTo 0

    'OPEN THE (TEMPLATE) FILE
    wrdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=FName

    'SET A VARIABLE TO REFERENCE ACTIVE DOCUMENT (TEMPLATE)
    Set tempDoc = wrdApp.ActiveDocument

    'DUPLICATE THE DOCUMENT
    wrdApp.Documents.Add wrdApp.ActiveDocument.FullName

    'SET A VARIABLE TO REFERENCE THE NEW VERSION OF DOCUMENT
    Set mrgDoc = wrdApp.ActiveDocument

    'CLOSE THE ORIGINAL (TEMPLATE) VERSION OF DOCUMENT
    tempDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'ACTIVATE THE NEW DOCUMENT
    mrgDoc.Activate

    'REPLACE PLACEHOLDER TEXT ITEMS WITH ACTUAL
    For Each cll In MergeData.Range(MergeData.Cells(1, 3).Address & ":" & MergeData.Cells(1, MergeData.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).Address)
        If cll.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
            repTx = cll.Value
       Else
            repTx = cll.Offset(1, 0).Value
        End If
        With mrgDoc.Content.Find
            .Text = cll.Value
            .Replacement.Text = repTx
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next cll

    'REPLACE TABLE 2 ON WORD DOC
    mrgDoc.Tables(2).Select
    For ii = 30 To 2 Step -1
        mrgDoc.Tables(2).Rows(ii).Delete
    Next ii
    wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

    'COPY AND PASTE TABLE 1 FROM EXCEL TO WORD
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    EO_DOC.Range("EO_TBL_INSCOPE_1").Copy
    wrdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True 

    ''''REMAINDER OF CODE AND COMPLETION CONFIRMATION TO USER''''

End Sub
```

I have tried a bunch of different things such as adding DoEvents, etc. to see if it would remedy the situation but have not yet found a solution.

Any VBA for MAC gurus out there?  Anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Office for Mac version are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Windows 7 and Office 2007, I believe my associate is using Office 2011 for MAC

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the location of wrdApp.Activate, which prevents Excel from doing the copy and Word from doing the paste. Here, in a cut down version of your code, I was able to make the Copy/Paste work by moving the statement so that it is immediately before the PasteExcelTable line. If you have to leave a copy of the line where it is, the problem is that (for example) Activating the Excel workbook immediately before you set CutCopyMode doesn't appear to be enough to get Excel to do the Copy properly. (BTW I am not a Mac VBA Guru!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It will be helpful if I run into a similar situation in the future, however, I already implemented a work-around which I was able to remove the copy/paste routine all-together.