# VBA : Pasting table from Excel to Word crashes on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

The following VBA code works perfectly in Windows to copy a table from Excel and paste it into a Word template.

On Mac the pasting step doesn't work and makes Excel and Word crash (no error message, just stop responding and I have to force quit).

I have tried using

```
.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```

instead of

```
.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
```

but I get the same behavior.

If I stop the macro before the last step, and paste manually into Word, it works. The table is correctly copied into the clipboard and I can paste it.

```
Sub testPasteMac()

Dim wordApp As Object
Dim FName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Copy the table from Excel
ws.Range("A1:E4").Copy

'Open Word
On Error Resume Next
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "word.Application")
If Err = 429 Then
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    Err.Clear
End If

'Display Word application
On Error Resume Next
wordApp.Activate
On Error GoTo 0

'Path to Word template file
FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "FileName.dotx"

'Open template as new file
wordApp.Documents.Add Template:=FName

'Paste clipboard into Word document
With wordApp
    .Selection.Goto what:=-1, Name:="bookmarkName"
    .Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    '.Selection.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
End With

End Sub
```

I use Excel for Mac version 16.18
VisualBasic 7.1

Comment: Seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349690/vba-copy-excel-table-to-word-works-on-pc-fails-on-mac
and
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6452bd86-acdb-45f4-ae65-3329ea5d38d7/selectionpasteexceltable-not-working-correctly-the-first-time-it-is-called?forum=vsto

Comment: Thanks. I checked and couldn't find anything helpful. I tried to add wordApp.Activate before pasting as described in your first link, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @c_georges - were you able to find a solution to this?  I'm running into a similar issue...

Comment: @Yoni Sorry, no solution.